# DELETE http://localhost:3001/formations/undefined 0 ()

Tags: node.js, angular, angular2-routing

Delete function no longer works.

I deleted my information from Delete HTTP call and it works but when I used in angular2 part front end it does not work anymore.

***error***
*DELETE http://localhost:3001/formations/undefined 0 ()*

*EXCEPTION: Response with status: 0  for URL: null*

*Subscriber.js:246 Uncaught Response {_body: ProgressEvent, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: Headers, …}*

*zone.js:2019 DELETE http://localhost:3001/formations/undefined 0 ()*

**this is my formation.Service**

```
deleteFormation(id){
    return this.http.delete("http://localhost:3001/formations/"+id)
        .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

**this is my home.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormationService } from '../../services/formation.service';
import { Formation } from '../../../app/formation';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-home1',
  templateUrl: './home1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home1.component.css']
})
export class Home1Component implements OnInit {

  formation: Observable<Formation[]>;


  constructor(  
      public formationService:FormationService

  ) { };

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formation = this.formationService.getFormations();
   // this.getFormations();
  }

  getFormations(){
    this.formationService.getFormations()
        .subscribe(formation=>{
          this.formation = this.formation;
        })


}

deleteFormation(id) {
  this.formationService.deleteFormation(id)
    .subscribe(()=>{
      this.getFormations();
    });
}
}
```

**this my home.html**

```
<app-navbar1></app-navbar1>



<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Title</b></td>
      <td><b>url</b></td>
      <td><b>description</b></td>
      <td width="275" align="center"><b>Action</b></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>  
     <tr *ngFor="let forms of formation  | async " >
        <td>{{forms.title}}</td>
        <td>{{forms.url}}</td> 
        <td>{{forms.description}}</td>
        <td width="275"> 
            <a class="btn btn-info" routerLink="/show/{{formation._id}}">Detail</a> 
            <a class="btn btn-success" routerLink="/edit/{{formation._id}}" >Edit</a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteFormation(formation._id)" >Delete</a>
        </td>
        </tr>


  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: By somehow, your id is undefined. Check the view which calls deleteFormation method in the component if the correct id is passed or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are enumerating over a collection in `*ngFor` and instead of passing an instance of an object to `deleteFormation` method, you are passing collection.

Instead of `deleteFormation(formation._id)` you need to call `deleteFormation(forms._id)`. `_id` does not exist on your `formation` array.

The same problem applies to your **Detail** and **Edit** links.

Comment: thank you , it works , but, it's still a small problem why I need to refresh the page when I click deleteFunction